# Failing to get WKT to reference for a multi-line

Tags: carto, well-known-text, polyline-creation

I have a shape that I've exported to CSV and GeoJSON to be loaded into CartoDB. Unfortunately, the GeoJSON doesn't work so I am trying to upload the CSV but don't quite understand how to get the array to reference, I am guessing I should convert it somewhere or somehow?

Ideally for free and with low bandwidth (I'm currently in Uganda). Here is the table for reference: https://alissarose.cartodb.com/tables/kcca_scrape_osm_linejoin4

Also, if the GeoJSON would just upload, that would be great. Here's a link to the file that won't load any data into CartoDB https://github.com/alissarose/test_spot/blob/master/kcca_OSMlinejoin.geojson

Answer (score 1):

The GeoJSON attached is failing because of the encoding:

```
ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x82
```

You can download it and save it as UTF-8 with your text editor and [it will work](http://team.cartodb.com/u/iriberri/viz/0622b30c-d859-11e4-ac8f-0e5e07bb5d8a/embed_map) (although it's probably too late!).